# IndexError::: List index out of range

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I wrote a code below. code is running.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    INPUT = sys.argv[1]
    assert len(sys.argv) == 2, '[USAGE] $ python %s C:/Users/NH/Pictures/Screenshots/img_6.jpg)' % (os.path.basename(__file__), INPUT)
    assert os.path.isfile(INPUT), '%s not found' % INPUT

    # read color image with grayscale flag: "cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE"
    img = cv2.imread(INPUT, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    # print grayscale image
    cv2.imwrite('grey_%s' % INPUT, img)
    print('Saved grayscale image @ grey_%s' % INPUT)
```

But when i try to run, i'm getting this error

```
INPUT = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can i fix this error. Thank!!!

Comment: I assume you named your python file `main.py`. You executed your python file with `python3 main.py` instead of `python3 main.py /path/to/an/image/file.png`

Comment: Yes it worked in cmd, but when i try to run in IDLE or Visual Studio it still giving me " list index out of range

Comment: You need to supply that information to your IDE. The `/parth/to/an/image/file.png` can be anything and the IDE cannot guess it. Google "Visual Studio execute Python with params".

Comment: Can  i supply path to my image in my code

Comment: You delete the two lines that contain `sys.argv` and you add the line `INPUT = '/path/to/an/image/file.png'`

Comment: It worked. i'm appreciated, thank

Answer (score 0):

IndexError means that your list is not long enough to include the index u wanted to call.

keep in mind:

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
print(a_list[1])
output: 2
```

since the first index is 0

Answer (score 0):

"sys.argv" stores the list of space-separated strings (called "command-line arguments") you entered into the terminal when you executed your program. sys.argv[0] is always the program name, and if you enter nothing else following your program name, none of the other slots in the list will be filled. When you have run this program, you must not have entered anything in addition to the program name, so [1] is not filled with anything.

In this case, it looks like you want this slot to be filled with a path to an image file. So instead of typing "python [program name].py" into your terminal, you need to type "python [program name].py [path to img file]".

Comment: it worked if i run it to cmd but when i run in IDLE is sitll giving me "list index out of range"